# how can i get class from the curent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 div which has this is li#click, and i want to get the class of this id.
I am trying to get class from de current div, but it come undefined.
i use "this" to get class on the clicked div only, because is there more div with the same function

i use the jquery function .attr('class') to get the class using the "this" keyword.
on the first time it work fine, but when i restart de pc it does not work anymore

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code para about device drop panel
    $( "li#click" ).click( () => {
        var classi = $(this).attr('class')
        alert(classi)
        let q = `#${classi}`

        $(q).toggleClass( "dados2" )

    });

});
```

i trying to get a class a name but it come undefined

Comment: how can 4 div with same id `#click`?, shouldn't be a class like `li.click` show us your htl code

Comment: Don't use an arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a regular function, not an arrow function. Arrow functions don't make their own `this` variable. Using an arrow function, your code would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code para about device drop panel
    $( "li#click" ).click(function() {
        var classi = $(this).attr('class')
        alert(classi)
        let q = `#${classi}`

        $(q).toggleClass( "dados2" )

    });

});
```